# Using a Cisco ASA 5505 to forward PXE (WDS) Requests

Tags: routing, dhcp, cisco-asa, pxe-boot, wds

I have a Cisco ASA 5505 that uses around 5 NICS for different networks.  Currently I'm using my ASA to route traffic as it's the only Cisco device I have capable of the small amount of routing required by my network.

Keeping things separate I use 5 NICS for different networks such as **outside**, **corp**, **printers**, **workstations**, **servers**, and **public**.  Each have a different subnet that I keep separate to control all the ACLs via the ASA firewall.  Everything (such as DHCP with a SuperScope) works great with the exception of the WDS Server.

My question is, currently I have a new PC plugged into the **workstations** NIC LAN that is looking for my WDS Server which is located on the **servers** LAN.  How can I get the requests from all the different NICs to flow to the **servers** NIC LAN?

Comment: Wow...  I love how people throw up an answer and others down vote it.  So they take it out on the OP asking a very valid question...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your question.  There was one answer, but it sucked, and was copied verbatim from another site, and didn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I'm not sure how much luck you'll have with the ASA as the router for this.. "'Tis a fine barn, but sure 'tis no pool" `s/barn/firewall/g`  `s/pool/router/g`

Comment: Yea I know thanks Tom.  I was pointing out how I'm sure the downvote came from the one/first answer poster.  Some people are more after the votes then the community...  Thanks for being the one to level things out!  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snap, Crackle, And Pop!  Found out what it was all thanks to Tom for giving me some good ideas.  I went to look into adding the DHCP option 66 to my scope options and thought to myself should I add it to the "servers" subnet scope options or the "workstations" subnet scope options...  I then slapped myself in the forehead when I realized the (unrecognized) PC trying to get an IP from the DHCP server was getting an IP from the "unknown" subnet I created for well..  Unknown PCs.. :)

The way my subnets are broke up are as follows...

```
10.71.3.0/27 (servers)
10.71.3.32/28 (printers)
10.71.3.48/29 (management)
10.71.3.128/25 (workstations)
10.80.1.0/24 (unknown)
```

I have all of the address pools from each subnet locked down to NOT hand out any ips.  The only subnet/scope that has available IPs is the "unknown" subnet.  This way if I have a reserved IP in one of the other subnets the machine gets that one.  If I don't it gets an IP on the dead/isolated/contained network (unknown).  Well it just so happens I did a good job with all my ACLs and the unknown can't get to anything except the DHCP server and there is no routing/nats for the unknown network.  So the PC was getting an IP but that's where it stopped.

Makes perfect sense and I would have never thought about it until Tom had me try something else.  So THANKS TOM!!!

As for the answer to this question the answer should be using something like the following in your asa config would work just fine...

```
dhcprelay server 10.71.3.2 servers
dhcprelay enable workstations
dhcprelay setroute workstations
dhcprelay timeout 60
```

10.71.3.2 in this case would be my DC/WDS server.  Setting "dhcprelay server 10.71.3.2 servers" allows that server to recieve the requests.  "dhcprelay enable workstations" should be defined for EACH subnet/interface/scope that needs access to the DHCP server.  "dhcprelay setroute workstations" as well should be defined for each (just as the enable lines are).  Timeout was my preference.

Answer (score 2):

I've never had much love for the ASA 5505 platform.. It's always seemed like a bit too "six of one, and half-dozen of the other" for me to find a use for it in any of my networks.

I've just spent the last half-hour reading a [bunch](http://www.richweb.com/can_the_cisco_asa_be_a_router) of [stuff](http://www.petri.co.il/cisco-asa-5500-series.htm) [about](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/29841) the [possibility](http://www.routerfreak.com/basic-configuration-tutorial-for-the-cisco-asa-5505-firewall/) of ["tricking it into routing"](http://www.packetu.com/2011/10/17/the-woes-of-using-an-asa-as-a-default-gateway/).

So, it basically boils down to this.

- With the base license, you can only use two VLANs (which is probably reasonably important).
- The routing table has lower priority than the translation table (This is bad, for routing performance).
- Without subtle commands, the ASA won't forward a packet back out of the same interface it came out of (`same-security-traffic permit intra-interface`, and `fixup protocol icmp`).

Those last two commands hark back to the day when the ASA range was the PIX range.

If I was in your position, I'd get a separate router, and keep the ASA, or replace the whole lot with a significantly more capable firewall, which is actually able to route traffic.

As the guys on the [Cisco forum have already mentioned to you](https://supportforums.cisco.com/message/4019397#4019397), dhcp-relay should fix everything for the DHCP portion of WDS and so on.

The question remains about the rest of PXE.  PXE is basically just DHCP and TFTP, which itself is a UDP-based service that runs on port 69.

Off the back of that.. have you tried setting a static NAT mapping for the WDS server on the interface in question, then point PXE at that with the `next-server` attribute?

Might work, but in order to set up enough NAT zones, you'd probably need to do them as VLANs and therefore, need the Security Plus license (25 VLANS!), and then theoretically be able to just do plain-ol' inter-VLAN routing, but I suspect you might have sucky performance.

Without labbing it up (a bit of a pain, as the ASAs are a pig to emulate, and I don't have a 5505), it's difficult to come up with a more accurate answer.

**More info:**

`next-server` is the ISC DHCPd's name for DHCP Option 66, as described here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#page-25 as **TFTP server name**.  It's the IP of the server where the TFTP server is located for PXE booting.

Static NAT is that process which allows you to configure a translation between two IP addresses that sit on different networks, as described [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa82/configuration/guide/nat_static.html).

Comment: Thanks Tom!  Yea I have the upgraded license and for the small network that is at this location I think it should do what is needed.  Everything seems like it's working fine and though not suggested I have found a way around everything thus far with the exception of the WDS Server issue.  I'm willing to give anything a shot though!  Two things...  1) When you say static NAT mapping what do you mean?  The workstations LAN can get/route to the server LAN with no problems at all.  2) What is next-server?  I looked on google for "asa 5505 next-server" and nothing came up.

Comment: Tom, just to confirm...  When you talk about static NAT that is just to make sure traffic can flow from subnet to subnet with no issues correct?  As stated above the servers subnet (ASA INT 2) can talk to the workstations subnet (ASA INT 3) with no issues at all.  As far as I can tell thats all you are saying to do with NAT.  Am I correct in assuming that?  Thanks!

Comment: Static NAT is basically what home routers call Port Forwarding (kinda...).  It means you can say that on one subnet (say `10.0.0.0/24`) that the IP `10.0.0.1` maps directly to the IP address `10.0.1.1` on the subnet `10.0.1.0/24`, so you'd still have to configure routes (static routes on your workstations, servers, etc), but it allows the traffic to traverse the subnets.

Comment: Static NAT is "traditionally" used to map public (external) IP addresses to internal ones, so you could effectively forward all traffic for a public IP address through the firewall, and poke it at an address on the internal LAN subnet.

Comment: Ahh nice! Never knew you could do that with the ASA 5505. Thanks for the tip. ;)